# Does /proc/ contains tid?

Tags: process, proc

I have process id 1234. This process contains thread id 1235.

When I use `ls -l /proc` I see only the pid (1234) but when I open the thread status file using `cat /proc/1235/status` I can see data.

Why is that?

Can I access with C code directly with tid? `/proc/1235/mem` without knowing the process id?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, `/proc` “contains” directory entries for thread identifiers as well as process identifiers, but only the latter are enumerated by `getdents`, so `ls` only shows process identifiers. This is described in [`man 5 proc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), in the “Overview” section, since [release 5.00 of the man-pages project](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/changelog.html#release_5.00):

> */proc/[pid]* subdirectories
>
> The */proc/[pid]* subdirectories are visible when iterating through */proc* with [`getdents(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) (and thus are visible when one uses [`ls(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) to view the contents of */proc*).
>
> */proc/[tid]* subdirectories
>
> The */proc/[tid]* subdirectories are *not* visible when iterating through */proc* with [`getdents(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) (and thus are *not* visible when one uses [`ls(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) to view the contents of */proc*).

> Why is that?

I suspect it’s to preserve backwards-compatibility (for programs written before threads existed in their current form on Linux), and to limit scalability problems.

> Can I access with C code directly with tid? `/proc/1235/mem` without know the process id?

Yes, if you know the tid you can access `/proc/${tid}` directly, without going through the pid.

If you want to enumerate threads, you can list the directory entries under `/proc/${tid}/task/` (this works with any thread identifier, not just process identifiers).

Comment: Is there any other command to view thread Id in /proc as ls command doesn't work?

Comment: "…I suspect it's to preserve compatibility…" My opinion is that it is linked to the fact that  The thread ID of the initial (main) thread is the same as the process ID of the entire process.

Comment: @MC68020 exactly, so programs expecting to find “pids” only in `/proc` don’t break since tids don’t appear there.

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav `ls /proc/*/task/`