# Linux cgroups: task vs pid?

Tags: linux-kernel, process, cgroups, terminology

What is the difference between a `task` and a `pid`? Inside of the `/sys/fs/cgroup` there a file called `tasks` which lists just pids,

```
$ ls /sys/fs/cgroup/*/tasks
/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/tasks        /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio/tasks
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/tasks      /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/tasks
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/tasks  /sys/fs/cgroup/net_prio/tasks
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/tasks       /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/tasks
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/tasks          /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/tasks
/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/tasks      /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma/tasks
/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/tasks      /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/tasks
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/tasks
```

`lsns` also provides an option which does this,

> `-p`, `--task pid` Display only the namespaces held by the process with this pid.

Why does cgroups call pid's tasks? Is there a distinction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`man cgroups`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html#CGROUPS_VERSION_1):

> In cgroups v1, a distinction is drawn between *processes* and
> *tasks*.  In this view, a process can consist of multiple tasks
> (more commonly called threads, from a user-space perspective, and
> called such in the remainder of this man page).  In cgroups v1,
> it is possible to independently manipulate the cgroup memberships
> of the threads in a process.
>
> The cgroups v1 ability to split threads across different cgroups
> caused problems in some cases.  For example, it made no sense for
> the *memory* controller, since all of the threads of a process
> share a single address space.  Because of these problems, the
> ability to independently manipulate the cgroup memberships of the
> threads in a process was removed in the initial cgroups v2
> implementation, and subsequently restored in a more limited form
> (see the discussion of "thread mode" below).

Generally speaking, tasks are threads in Linux; see also `/proc/*/task`, and [the hidden `/proc` entries for tids](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/608297/86440).